# Application requires Admin privileges, but Admin account is in use (Win 10 Pro)

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, uac

I try to install UPS monitor application from producer site: `http://fideltronik.com/files/ups-monitor/UPSmon3en.msi` .

After instalation, application tries to run services, but message appears:

```
Error during starting UPS Monitor Server 3.0.
Can't install service - code: 1310.
You must have administrative privileges to perform this operation.
```

The answer from producer is to turn of UAC, but i'm not happy with this solution. Any suggestions, which I can send to producer?

**update**

Turning OFF UAC changes nothing.

Comment: Did you try this: right click on the file ----> run as administrator.

Comment: @JayT. Can't no such possibility - this is .msi

Answer (score 0):

It is strange - but works. Right click on file, compatibility, I select run this program in compatibilty mode (selected previuos windows), BUT before OK  I press button RUN COMPATIBILITY TROUBLESHOOTER, and everything goes right... Thank you Microsoft...